# Java get unread emails

Tags: java, email, pop3

I'm writing a code to read email from gmail. So the first time I launch, it reads new emails. That's fine. But I want when I launch it a second time, it doesn't get same emails it got before.

For example if there are 3 unread emails, when I launch for the first time, it gets the 3. But When I launch again, it gets nothing (because it already got 3). And if there is a new email and I launch it again, it should get only the last one and not the 3 firsts.

Hope I'm clear enough.

I use the code from http://alvinalexander.com/java/javamail-search-unseen-unread-messages-mailbox-pop3

```
package javamailtests;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.search.*;

public class JavaMailSearchInbox {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    // mail server info
    String host = "pop.gmail.com";
    String user = "USER";
    String password = "PASS";

    // connect to my pop3 inbox in read-only mode
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
    store.connect(host, user, password);
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    // search for all "unseen" messages
    Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
    FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false);
    Message messages[] = inbox.search(unseenFlagTerm);

    if (messages.length == 0) System.out.println("No messages found.");

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      // stop after listing ten messages
      if (i > 10) {
        System.exit(0);
        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();
      }

      System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
      System.out.println("From : " + messages[i].getFrom()[0]);
      System.out.println("Subject : " + messages[i].getSubject());
      System.out.println("Sent Date : " + messages[i].getSentDate());
      System.out.println();
    }

    inbox.close(true);
    store.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: @CarlPalsson No. That's a client option. It's not an essential feature of POP3. You get to choose whether messages stay at or are deleted from the server. What really happens is that the client goes to extra trouble to delete the messages if you select that option.

Comment: Retrieving gmail emails from that host is going to be tricky

Answer (score 1):

I've just made this ugly example. And it worked, it retrieves all messages including those that have been seen.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

try {
    Store store = App.session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", "email", "password");

    Folder folder = App.store.getFolder("Inbox");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    Message[] msgs = folder.getMessages();

    for (Message msg : msgs) {
        System.out.println(msg.getSubject());
    }
}catch(MessagingException e)    {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Of course you will have to properly retrieve just the mails you need, otherwise if you have an old email account this code will start a very heavy process.

I hope this could be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest returning the old messages that were read to "Mark as Unread" ?

Comment: Yes, but if I do that, next time I read them I'll get the same messages right ?

Comment: Do you mean "mark as read" ? if so, how can I know if my client has already read something or not ? I mean for example, let say thunderbird, how does he know on the server which is new email for him and what is old ? does he store an id or something locally and then check on the server from where he should start ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.mail.*;

   public class ReadingEmail {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "example@gmail.com", "Password");

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
        Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
        for (Address address : in) {
            System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
        }
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
        BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
        System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
        System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
        System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
             } catch (Exception mex) 
         mex.printStackTrace();
                    }
             }
        }
```